# Как дать ссылку на свой сервер?

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер

На работе сказали создать и дать ссылку на свой сервер, для того чтоб они сами не поднимали сервер. Залить туда проект и дать им. Что это? Это связано с FTP-сервером? Я понятия не имею что это и как сделать.

Comment: Ну так спросите их, что они имеют в виду :)

Comment: Они считают что я знаю как это сделать. А спрашивать как это и что это поздно. Но я понятно объяснил о чем я? Может знаете где можно инфу взять

Comment: У тебя вообще белый адрес-то? а то возьми какой халявный хостинг с FTP-доступом, вывали туда свой проект и дай им адрес да логин-пароль... или вообще расшарь его через дропбокс или там яндекс-диск...